# Proof there is a irrational number $r$ in $a < b$ so that $a < r < b$

Tags: analysis, irrational-numbers

I have a understanding problem of the following proof versus my own attempt.
I don't get **why you need another intervall in between** in which you "place" the shifted version of $\sqrt2$

$\sqrt2$ is irrational (already prooven)

$1 < \sqrt2 < 2~~ \mid ~~-1$

$0 < \sqrt2 -1 < 1$

There are $c$ and $d \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $a < c < d < b$ such that $(c,d) \subseteq (a,b)$.

$0 < \sqrt2 -1 < 1 ~~ \mid  \cdot ~~(d-c)$

$0 < (\sqrt2 -1)\cdot(d-c) < d-c$

[$\sqrt2 -1 := x$]

$0 < x\cdot(d-c) < d-c ~~ \mid +~~c$

$c < x\cdot(d-c)+c < d$

$[x\cdot(d-c)+c := r]$

So now we have to proof $r$ is irrational. We can do that by Proof by Contradiction:

*Let $r$ be rational.* Then $\frac{r-c}{d-c}-1$ must be rational too.

$\frac{x\cdot(d-c)+c-c}{d-c}-1 = x-1 = (\sqrt2 + 1)-1 =\sqrt2 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\square$

Now my attempt without the $c$ and $d$ part:

$1 < \sqrt2 <2 ~~ \mid - ~~ 1$

$0 < \sqrt2-1 <1 ~~\mid \cdot ~~ (b-a)$

$0 < (\sqrt2-1)\cdot(b-a) <b-a ~~\mid + ~~ a$

$a < (\sqrt2-1)\cdot(b-a)+a <b$

Suppose $(\sqrt2-1)\cdot(b-a) =: r$ is rational, then $\frac{r-a}{b-a}+1$ must be rational too.

$\frac{(\sqrt2-1)\cdot(b-a)+a-a}{b-a}+1 = (\sqrt2-1)+1 = \sqrt2 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\square$

Comment: The reason "you need another intervall in between" is because $a$ might be irrational and be such that $r = a + (\sqrt{2}-1)(b-a)$ becomes rational. By taking the extra step to locate a rational interval $[c,d]$ inside $[a,b]$ we rule out this possibillity. However one can do this a bit simpler (imo) as in the answer below by spliiting the proof into two cases: 1) $a$ rational and 2) $a$ irrational.

Comment: Philosophically, I dislike these proofs, because numbers of the form $a + \frac{\sqrt 2}{n}$ (or similar variations) are "sparse" in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Considering the different cases is also unelegant. Here's a one liner: $|(a,b)| = \mathbf c$ and $|(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}| = \aleph_0$. This implies $(a,b) \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is nonempty, and in fact uncountable.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I disagree. I think it's much more inellegent to use 'too strong tools for the job'. Your one liner works, but it requires knowing some things about countabillity. Keep in mind that problems like this are usually given in the very start at a basic calculus course where the concepts you use are completely unknown to the student and once you do know these concepts then the statement here is something you don't need to prove as it's just so obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ is rational, $\displaystyle \frac{r-c}{d-c}$ must be rational, because both $c$ and $d$ are rational numbers. And then, you get a contradiction. So $r$ becomes irrational.

However, in your "proof", if $r$ is rational, then $\displaystyle \frac{r-a}{b-a}$ may not be rational when $a$ is rational but $b$ is irrational. In that case, $r-a$ would be rational and $b-a$ would be irrational.

For instance, take $a=-1$ and $b=\sqrt 2$. Then $(\sqrt 2-1) \cdot (b-a) = (\sqrt 2-1)(\sqrt 2 +1) = 1=r$. So, $r$ becomes a rational number. So, you cannot derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative argument:

If $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, pick $n$ such that $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}<(b-a)$. Then $a<a+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}<b$ and $a+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ is irrational.

If $a\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, pick $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<(b-a)$. Then $a<a+\frac{1}{n}<b$ and $a+\frac{1}{n}$ is irrational.